# Calling a Telegram Token from an external file

Tags: token, python-telegram-bot

I couldn't seem to find anything regarding this and I know I had a solution months ago. I want to write a Telegram Bot with python-telegram-bot to download videos from any (legal) website and send it to the user.

The Bot should ask the User whether he wants a Video, Audio(mp3) or a GIF(mp4 w/o audio). This should happen via Inline Keyboard. I'm getting away from my initial question...

I don't want to have the Token inside the script, as I might share it with others for more specific help. So how do I call the token from an external "token.txt" to be used within my python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
import os
with open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/token.txt') as file:
    TOKEN = file.readline().strip()
updater = Updater(TOKEN)
```

I'm assuming that this is inside the "runner" script which shall be in the same directory as the token text file. The `dirname/realpath` stuff is to make it work even if you call the runner script from another directory.

I do the same thing with my bot and I added the `token.txt` to `.gitignore` ;-)

Comment: This is more helpful than what I have gotten from the official group.

I still have to try and set up git on my win10 for Visual Studio Code, and wil implement what you suggested. Thank you!