# Telegram bot to download videos via YouTube-DL?

Tags: youtube-dl, python-telegram-bot

I want to write a telegram bot with the python-telegram-bot package that waits for a url from the user and then asks the user what format he wants the file in.

I had a question regarding calling a token from external sources, which has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51222123/1004595).

How would I have to write the bot, so a user doesn't have to call a command, but can send a URL (e.g. https://youtube.com, www.youtube.com or just youtube.com, same for reddit, twitter, etc.)? I would then want the bot to send back a inline keyboard to ask for the format (Video, Audio, or Gif) and send it their way. (also delete the file from the local server afterwards).

The bot will be utilizing [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) to download the videos and convert them to the chosen format. I want to use different presets for different websites/chosen formats. If someone sends a url and chooses GIF, it should automatically choose the preset to remove the audio from the video. Telegram will then recognize it as a gif and auto-play it in chat.

Comment: I know it's a really old message, but I've run into this topic and I found this:
https://alerom90.medium.com/how-i-made-my-girlfriend-happy-with-a-simple-telegram-bot-2be8e4b150e7